# Sending and Recieving variable to and from c# and JS using cefsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am new to whole cefsharp browser communication and I have a browser which is loading my custom html js and a richtextbox.

I need to communicate between these both where if somebody enters something to the richtextbox it will automatically send it as a variable to the browser where my custom js will get it and similarly if some person enters something in my browser, a js function will send it to c# as a variable which will update the richtextbox.

Sending the variable from js to c# is working using **RegisterAsyncJSObject** but when after the above works and updates my richtextbox and I enter something in the richtextbox then **ExecuteScriptAsync** doesnot work but if i remove everything that the **RegisterAsyncJSObject** has updated in the richtextbox and enter something to richtextbox then **ExecuteScriptAsync** works

Here is the code

**Creating a AsyncJSObject:**

```
mw = ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow);
CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
MainWindowBrowser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("getTEXTfromjs", mw);
```

**JS Code**

```
getHTMLfromjs.updateonDrag(result);
```

**AsycnJSObject Code that updates richtextbox:**

```
public void updateonBrowserEnter(String rtbHolder) {
  this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
   richtextbox.Text = rtbHolder;
  });
 }
```

**ExecuteScriptAsync Code on Richtextbox TextChanged:**

```
String rtbh = richtextbox.Text;
MainWindowBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(String.Format("testFunc('{0}');", rtbh));
```

Comment: You can use the new PostMessage feature to simplify your code see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775

Comment: Past that it's not clear what exactly your problem is, please reread your question and try to clarify.

Comment: RegisterAsyncJSObject has been removed which indicates you are using an old outdated version.

Comment: I need to simply send and receive something (a variable) to and from js and c#

Comment: I cannot tell much from the  code you've posted. When the methods are called matters. 79.1.360 is the current supported version. Updating the UI should be done in an asynchronous fashion or you risk blocking a thread.

Comment: If TextChanged is called when you update the text then your code be be in a deadlock.

Comment: Your case might actually be it's stuck in a loop.

Comment: Everthing else is working I just need to know how can you pass a variable in a method from c# to js
I am using this,
frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("testFunc()", myvar);
but it gives undefined @amaitland

Comment: Remove the brackets,

Comment: Even after removing the brackets passing the variable just doesnot seem to trigger the js function from c# if I pass it variables
frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("testFunc", myvar);
Could you point me to some working examples of passing variables from c# to js @amaitland Sorry for the trouble but I am new to all this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everything seems to be working 
The first porblem which was communication between js to c# was solved using
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#async-javascript-binding-jsb

The second problem was communication between c# to js was that when I executed

```
frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(String.Format("testFunc('{0}')", myvar));
```

Js just doesnot seem to accept multi-line string with single quotes (' ') so In my case I had two options

- One convert it to Single line string using regex
- Two use (**`**) instead of usual single-quotes which will be

  frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(String.Format("testFunc(`{0}`)", myvar));

and it solved the issue